# How to add padding between paragraph and list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my footer I have breadcrumb list and under that is some text.

My question then is how to set the padding between the breadcrumb list and the Copyright paragraph.

I solved this using `<br>` tag, but I think it's not semantically correct.

I tried with padding-top but without success.

```css
.col-xs-12 .breadcrumb{
     background-color: #2b2b2b;
    }
    .breadcrumb > li + li:before {
      content: none;
    }
    .breadcrumb li a    {
        color: white;
        font-family: TW Cen MT;
     font-size:17px;
    }
    .container-fluid  p{
    
      bottom: 0;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 34em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                
                <img src="img/Gallery/fb.png" alt=""> &nbsp
                <img src="img/Gallery/twitter.png" alt=""> &nbsp
                <img src="img/Gallery/youtube.png" alt=""> &nbsp
                <img src="img/Gallery/myspace.png" alt="">
    
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>  &nbsp
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>  &nbsp
                <li> <a href="#">FAQ</a></li>   &nbsp
                <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ol>
    
                <p><small>Copyright <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>  All Right Reserved | Testing Website </small></p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to see the issue?

Comment: How to import Bootstrap on jsfiddle?

Comment: I put my bet on the `position: absolute` messing things up.

Comment: All p, including the on in your footer has a large margin-left of 34 em.

Comment: I've added the `bootstrap` tag to your question.

Comment: @IgorSimic use a CDN

Comment: [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `margin-bottom` to the ordered list, like so:

```
.breadcrumb {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me is this semantically correct, I think on complete code.

.col-xs-12 .breadcrumb{
 background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  content: none;
}
.breadcrumb li a    {
    color: white;
    font-family: TW Cen MT;
 font-size:17px;
}
.container-fluid  p{
    
      bottom: 0;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 34em;
    }
.breadcrumb {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
}

Comment: @IgorSimic New questions or a follow up to the current one shouldn't be posted in the comments. Create a new post instead. If this answer solves your original problem mark it as the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a margin-bottom:; to the list (.breadcrumb), and please remove the properties

```
.container-fluid  p{
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 34em;
}
```

you won't need them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your paragraph is positionned in absolute, it's out the flow.

**1st solution**
Remove absolute positionning.

**2nd solution**
Add a padding-bottom in your list.
The size of padding correspond to the height of the paragraph and the margin you want.

Like so:

```
.breadcrumb {
    padding-bottom: 50px; // 20px height paragraph, 30px height margin
}
```